# How to update a user's tags ? using Quickblox javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, quickblox

How can i update a user' tags using Quickblox javascript SDK ?
i tried using the following parameter names :

```
user_tags
tags
```

using

```
var params = {
    user_tags: ["testing"]
};
```

Please don't answer me with "you can use custom objects, etc.." i'm already using them for something else.
I want to use tags, and nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the table on this page: http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Update_API_User_by_identifier you should use `tag_list` key which accepts a comma separated list of tags.

```
QB.users.update(user_id, { tag_list: "tag1,tag2" }, callback);
```

Unfortunately QB docs aren't the best in the world...

Comment: Thx ! i totaly agree, i lost hours searching for examples that didn't work well and finally i got what i wanted by downloading the sources and searching for QB functions... i posted the same question on their Github, fortunately a guy replied quickly too